# What is the word for two or more people realise that something is happening but when no one will openly express it? A competition or problem, perhaps

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing about the competition we have with our friends on who looks the best on social media. I am trying to describe like an unidentified fight or competition with our peers. Like, no one is going to acknowledge that we are competing against each other but everyone knows deep down that it kinda is a competition.

The sentence is

> - *Even on days where I feel particularly confident with myself, I scroll on social media to see my classmates looking so beautiful and skinny in bikinis, no roll or stretch marks in sight, and I immediately feel defeated in the _____ fight for bodily supremacy.*

Feel free to help alter this sentence in the best way. Just like an unacknowledged competition...?

EDIT: thanks guys for all your input!! very helpful!! <3

Comment: Things which are understood / assumed by conversants without being explicitly stated are ***implicit***. Other relevant words include ***undertone, inference, subtext,...*** and expressions like ***it goes without saying***.

Comment: Unspoken seems apt: ". . . and I immediately felt defeated in the unspoken fight for bodily supremacy."

Answer (score 1):

"...and I immediately feel defeated in the **undeclared** competition for bodily supremacy."

> - [undeclared](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undeclared) - not announced or openly acknowledged : not stated or decided in an official way : not declared, an undeclared war. (**MW**)

- "There was an undeclared competition among us."
- "I also remember an undeclared competition among the students."

Answer (score 1):

**Tacit** would suggest something unspoken but inferred or implied in the situation. Oxford English Dictionary, "[tacit, adj.](https://oed.com/view/Entry/196904)":

> 2. Not openly expressed or stated, but implied; understood, inferred.

That has the benefit of suggesting something both *not openly expressed* and *understood* or felt by the participants.

> Even on days where I feel particularly confident with myself, I scroll on social media to see my classmates looking so beautiful and skinny in bikinis, no roll or stretch marks in sight, and I immediately feel defeated in the **tacit** fight for bodily supremacy.

Answer (score 0):

You presumably discounted *unacknowledged*. Starting from your suggestion that the competition is not acknowledged, there is a range of words that may fit the specification. Here are a couple of other *un-...* words:

> *undeclared* = Not publicly announced, admitted, or acknowledged
>
> [Oxford Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/undeclared)

> *unspoken* = not stated, although thought, understood, or felt
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unspoken)

and here are two other possibilities:

> *tacit* = understood without being expressed directly
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tacit)

> *latent* = present and capable of emerging or developing but not now visible, obvious, active
>
> [Merriam Webstre](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/latent)

To me, *latent* and *undeclared* have slight feelings of a possible future admission of the competition. I feel *unstated* and *tacit* are nice because they relate more strongly to the mute understanding of the presence of the competition.

Answer (score -1):

You may not get closer than **palpable**.

From [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/palpable) (amended):

> *palpable*  [adjective]
>
> The prototypical meaning is that when something is palpable, you can
> touch or handle it.  However, the word is often used to describe
> things that usually can't be handled or touched, such as emotions or
> sensations.
>
> You probably won't see *palpable* used to describe, say, an egg or a
> doorknob or a motorcycle. Palpable is usually reserved for situations
> in which something invisible becomes so intense that it feels as
> though it has substance or weight. Someone who has experienced a death
> in the family might say that her grief feels palpable.

Thus

... *I immediately feel defeated in the palpable fight/struggle for bodily supremacy.*

Comment: I could understand a downvote for answering a question considered to lack reasonable research.Though I doubt 'palpable' would have been easily found. However, I feel this is not the reason here. I'd appreciate explanation as to why this is considered an inappropriate answer, if the downvoter is really seeking the best interests of the site (to promote the understanding and mastery of English).